# What to use instead of the 'new' statement in bukkit plugins/java

Tags: java, bukkit

Well, I'm tring to make a bukkit plugin that checks for a YAML file called 'config.yml' but to do that I would need to do:

```
Config = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "config.yml");
Configs = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(Config);
```

But, that also creates it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What creates what if what doesn't exist? The first line will *not* create a file on the filesystem, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* you just want:

```
if (Config.exists()) {
    Configs = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(Config);
}
```

(Now would be a good time to learn about Java naming conventions, by the way - variables in Java conventionally start with a lower-case letter.)